# Create infinite scrolling effect using Firebase Realtime Database data in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat, infinite-scroll

I am integrating a chat feature in my mobile application, and decided to use Firebase Realtime Database for the backend instad of Firestore as a cost reduction mechanism. I am running into a problem, however. There seems to be very sparse documentation on how to create infinite scrolling using data from `Realtime Database` instead of `Firestore`.

Below is the organization of my chat messages. This is the query I want to use:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance
            .ref("messages/${widget.placeID}")
            .orderByChild("timeStamp")
```

And this is the widget I want to return for each result:

```
MessageWidget(
  message: message.text,
  id: message.uid,
  name: message.name,
  lastSender: message.lastSender,
  date: message.timeStamp,
  profilePicture: message.profilePicture,
);
```

Here is the database structure
[image]

The query works, and I have already programmed the MessageWidget from the JSON response of the query. All I need is for the query to be called whenever it reaches the top of its scroll, and load more `MessageWdiget`s. Also note, this is a chat app where users are scrolling up, to load older messages, to be added above the previous.

Thank you!

**EDIT**: here is the code I currently have:

```
Flexible(
  child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref("messages/${widget.placeID}")
        .orderByChild("timeStamp")
        .limitToLast(20)
        .onValue,
    builder:
        (context, AsyncSnapshot<DatabaseEvent> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else {
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> map =
            snapshot.data!.snapshot.value as dynamic;
        List<dynamic> list = [];
        list.clear();
        list = map.values.toList();
        return Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                // shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final json = list[index]
                      as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
                  final message = Message.fromJson(json);
                  return MessageWidget(
                    message: message.text,
                    id: message.uid,
                    name: message.name,
                    lastSender: message.lastSender,
                    date: message.timeStamp,
                    profilePicture:
                        message.profilePicture,
                  );
                }),
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
),
```

My initState

```
void initState() {
   super.initState();

   _scrollController.addListener(() {
     if (_scrollController.position.atEdge) {
       bool isTop = _scrollController.position.pixels == 0;
       if (isTop) {
         //add more messages

       } else {
         print('At the bottom');
       }
     }
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of testing code, I came up with the following solution
The first step is to declare a `ScrollController` in your state class.

```
final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
```

You will also need to declare a `List` to store query results

```
List list = [];
```

Next, use the following function to get initial data

```
  getStartData() async {
    //replace this with your path
    DatabaseReference starCountRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('messages/${widget.placeID}');
    starCountRef
        .orderByChild("timeStamp")
        //here, I limit my initial query to 6 results, change this to how many 
        //you want to load initially
        .limitToLast(6)
        .onChildAdded
        .forEach((element) {
      setState(() {
        list.add(element.snapshot.value);
        list.sort((a, b) => a["timeStamp"].compareTo(b["timeStamp"]));
      });
    });
  }
```

Run this in `initState`

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    getStartData();
  }
```

Now to display the initial data that was generated when the page was loaded, build the results into a `ListView`

```
ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: list.length,
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    //here I use a premade widget, replace MessageWidget with 
                    //what you want to load for each result
                    itemBuilder: (_, index) => MessageWidget(
                      message: list[index]["text"],
                      date: list[index]["timeStamp"],
                      id: list[index]["uid"],
                      profilePicture: list[index]["profilePicture"],
                      name: list[index]["name"],
                      lastSender: list[index]["lastSender"],
                    ),
                  ),
```

Note that your `ListView` must be constrained, meaning that you can scroll to the beginning or end of your `ListView`. Sometimes, the `ListView` won't have enough data to fill and be scrollable, so you must declare a height with a `Container` or bound it to its contents.

Now you have the code that fetches data when the page is loaded using `getStartData()` and `initState`. The data is stored in `list`, and a `ListView.builder` builds a `MessageWidget` for each item returned by  `getStartData`. Now, you want to load more information when the user scrolls to the top.

```
  getMoreData() async {
    var moreSnapshots = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref("messages/${widget.placeID}")
        .orderByChild("timeStamp")
        .endBefore(list[0]["timeStamp"])
        .limitToLast(20)
        .once();
    var moreMap = moreSnapshots.snapshot.value as dynamic;
    setState(() {
      list.addAll(moreMap.values.toList());
      list.sort((a, b) => a["timeStamp"].compareTo(b["timeStamp"]));
    });
  }
```

Then, make the function run when the `ListView.builder` is scrolled all the way to the top by adding this to the already existing `initState`.

```
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.atEdge) {
        bool isTop = _scrollController.position.pixels == 0;
        if (isTop) {
          getMoreData();
        }
      }
    });
```

Hopefully this helps or gives you a pointer on where to go from here. Thanks to Frank van Puffelen for his help on which query to use based on the previous answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your code already loads all messages.

---

If you want to load a maximum number of messages, you'll want to put a limit on the number of messages you load. If you want to load only the newest messages, you'd use `limitToLast` to do so - as the newest messages are last when you order them by their `timeStamp` value.

So to load for example only the 10 latest messages, you'd use:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .ref("messages/${widget.placeID}")
    .orderByChild("timeStamp")
    .limitToLast(10);
```

This gives you the limited number of messages to initially show in the app.

---

Now you need to load the 10 previous messages when the scrolling reaches the top of the screen. To do this, you need to know the `timeStamp` value and the key of the message that is at the top of the screen - so of the oldest message you're showing so far.

With those two values, you can then load the previous 10 with:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .ref("messages/${widget.placeID}")
    .orderByChild("timeStamp")
    .endBefore(timeStampValueOfOldestSeenItem, keyOfOldestSeenItem)
    .limitToLast(10);
```

The database here again orders the nodes on their `timeStamp`, it then finds the node that is at the top of the screen based on the values you give, and it then returns the 10 nodes right before that.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the question with code I currently have, but I would like to know how to run your code when the user scrolls all the way to the top, then add the new items above. I used a ```scrollController``` to detect when the user is at the top, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: I wrote my answer based on the extremely limited code that you initially shared. Does my answer make sense in the context of that code and in general? If so, instead of asking me to apply the answer to the complete code you now shared, I recommend you try to apply it yourself - and post a new question if you run into more specific problems when you do.

Comment: I re asked the question with more detailed code. I have looked into the code you have generously provided and examples online, but am still unaware of how to proceed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74563664/dynamically-add-new-data-to-listview-builder-in-flutter-when-user-scrolls-to-top

Comment: I added an answer to this question below, was wondering if you had any input on the application of your solution.