# Dynamically add new data to Listview.builder in flutter when user scrolls to top

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, infinite-scroll

I previously asked a question on how to load new messages with Firebase Realtime Database using infinite scrolling.

Here is the code I currently use to list `MessageWidgets` in my chat application

This runs when the chat screen opens:

```
void initState() {
   super.initState();

   _scrollController.addListener(() {
     if (_scrollController.position.atEdge) {
       bool isTop = _scrollController.position.pixels == 0;
       if (isTop) {
         //add more messages

       } else {
         print('At the bottom');
       }
     }
   });
 }
```

This is the code for the list of messages:

```
Flexible(
  child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref("messages/${widget.placeID}")
        .orderByChild("timeStamp")
        .limitToLast(20)
        .onValue,
    builder:
        (context, AsyncSnapshot<DatabaseEvent> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else {
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> map =
            snapshot.data!.snapshot.value as dynamic;
        List<dynamic> list = [];
        list.clear();
        list = map.values.toList();
        return Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                // shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final json = list[index]
                      as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
                  final message = Message.fromJson(json);
                  return MessageWidget(
                    message: message.text,
                    id: message.uid,
                    name: message.name,
                    lastSender: message.lastSender,
                    date: message.timeStamp,
                    profilePicture:
                        message.profilePicture,
                  );
                }),
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
```

Based on the https://stackoverflow.com/a/74562746/16727709, I am wondering how to load more messages when the user scrolls to the top.

The list initially loads data for this query:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .ref("messages/${widget.placeID}")
    .orderByChild("timeStamp")
    .limitToLast(20);
```

I would like to run this query and update the Listview.builder by adding the results of this query when the user scrolls to the top

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .ref("messages/${widget.placeID}")
    .orderByChild("timeStamp")
    .endBefore(timeStampValueOfOldestSeenItem, keyOfOldestSeenItem)
    .limitToLast(10);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What did you do with the code I gave in answer to your previous question? Did you try adding it to your `if (isTop) {` condition? What happened when you did that?

Comment: I found success when creating a variable called ```limit``` and setting it to 10 on ```initState```, concatenating it into the query and increasing its value by 10 whenever ```isTop``` was true. I scrapped that idea since it would still load alot of data instead of adding it. As for the code you provided in the previous example, I understand the principle of retrieving data between two timestamps, but I don't know how to retrieve ```timeStampValueOfOldestSeenItem``` or ```keyOfOldestSeenItem``` as well as getting the data outside of the ```listView``` and adding it to the ListView.

Comment: All of the values are in the `snapshot` you get in your builder, and in the `map` you extract from that. The timestamp values are even in the `list` that you create too. You'll need to find those values, and make them available to the scroll listener. Take it one step at a time: set a breakpoint on the first line where you access `snapshot.data!.snapshot` and run in a debugger. Inspect the variables? Are the values you need in there?

Comment: I think I got it:
I defined two variables in the top of the class and set them like this

```first = list[0]["timeStamp"];
last = list[list.length - 1]["timeStamp"];```
I printed the values to confirm they were correct, and they are. I didn't use ```snapshot.data!.snapshot```

Comment: That gives you the timestamp. If there's a chance that multiple messages have the same timestamp value, you need to also know the key to disambiguate between those. But if you have a working solution, please post it as an answer below so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: I was able to do the first step of getting the end timeStamp, but what is ```keyOfOldestSeenItem``` and how do I get it?

Comment: If you check your `map` in the debugger, you should find the keys there. You're dropping them when you convert that map to a `list` though.

Comment: Even if got the query I should use, my main problem is how do I run it, get it's data, then add it somehow to the existing list.

Comment: You'll either need to create a custom stream for your `StreamBuilder`, or set is in the state with `setState` and work from that. All of these are separate steps towards your complex use-case, but in its totality it is well beyond the scope we can reasonable answer succinctly in a single question on Stack Overflow. Going forward, please break your highly complex use-case of "implementing infinite scroll in my Flutter chat app" up into more manageable questions, such as "how to get a previous page of data from Firestore?", "how to respond to the scrolling?" and "how to update the state later?".